# Cabal update fails with unix package configure error

Tags: haskell, cabal, configure, linux-mint, cabal-install

I have a very old Cabal (1.16.0) installed from my distro's repo (Linux Mint). Today, I tried updating it and got:

```
cabal install cabal-install -v3
...
unix-2.7.2.2 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
zlib-0.6.1.2 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I also see

```
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/tmp/unix-2.7.2.2-2138/unix-2.7.2.2':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
sh returned ExitFailure 1
```

After checking the config.log, I see some errors but I am not sure they are related and the configuration failed on them:

```
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 
configure:2738: $? = 0
configure:2727: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2738: $? = 4
configure:2727: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2738: $? = 4
configure:2758: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:2780: gcc -Wl,--hash-size=31 -Wl,--reduce-memory-overheads   conftest.c  >&5
configure:2784: $? = 0
configure:2832: result: yes
configure:2835: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:2837: result: a.out
configure:2843: checking for suffix of executables
configure:2850: gcc -o conftest -Wl,--hash-size=31 -Wl,--reduce-memory-overheads   conftest.c  >&5
configure:2854: $? = 0
configure:2876: result: 
configure:2898: checking whether we are cross compiling
configure:2906: gcc -o conftest -Wl,--hash-size=31 -Wl,--reduce-memory-overheads   conftest.c  >&5
```

This is weird (I tried running the gcc.. command and it was also fine). Any help with this error is welcome.

Comment: The errors are not necessarily in the end of config.log, you need to search for the string 'error'.

Comment: You are right @n.m. I did the search and found some errors but I am not sure configuration failed on them. See the updated description above.

Comment: These errors are harmless, it's the configure script trying to figure out usable gcc options. There should be more error messages. You are probably interested in one that sits near "checking whether we are cross compiling" message.

Comment: @n.m. if you mean the config.log's messages near "checking we are...", then I copy-pasted everything into the post above. The log just suddently ends with "configure:2906: gcc -o conftest...".

Comment: Another alternative (better IMO) is to just use Stack: https://haskell-lang.org/get-started

Comment: @Sibi I would like to write a Haskell program that acts like a standalone script (with runhaskell) - I am not sure stack is an alternative for me (I would need new cabal's sandboxes).

Comment: @user1724641 You can use the scripting functionality for it: https://haskell-lang.org/tutorial/stack-script

Comment: @Sibi not bad! I mean I could use this. This way I will need to `stack new` etc. and add the needed package descriptor files (yaml, etc).

Comment: @user1724641 Note that you don't need `stack new` for the script interpreter feature. Also you don't need `yaml` files. It is an independent script with just one file. You can see the `script interpreter` section in that page to understand it better. All you need to do is `./http.hs` to execute it.

Comment: @Sibi this `stack` way of doing things looks quite cool, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the `cabal-install` binary for linux from the cabal homepage as well: https://www.haskell.org/cabal/download.html